# display div's side by side after parent div height reached

Tags: html, css

I am having a div and it will consists of n number of div's

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"> top left     </div>
        <div class="child"> mid left     </div>
        <div class="child"> bottom left  </div>
        <div class="child"> top right    </div>
        <div class="child"> mid right    </div>
        <div class="child"> bottom right </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display them side by side by keeping some `max-height` for either wrapper or parent.

Example: first three childs will be in as first column, next three will be second column and last one will be in third column.

I tried everything `display: inline-block`, `float: left`, `padding`, `max-height` but none worked.

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/J3yTP/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="parent">
<div class="col">
            <div class="child">one</div>
            <div class="child">cas</div>
            <div class="child">asds</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
            <div class="child">wdw</div>
            <div class="child">abc</div>
            <div class="child">def</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
            <div class="child">ghi</div>
            <div class="child">jkl</div>
            <div class="child">mno</div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
max-width: 100%;
}
.col {
width: 33%;
float: left
}
```

Edit: Changed to meet your requirement.
If you want it to automatically arrange like this, based on parent height or item count or anything else, you will have to use javascript. Not possible with CSS alone.

Comment: it will but in this they will form like x-axis, but i want them to form like y-axis

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
}

.child {
width: 33%;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: It would help to explain why this fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

i have created fiddle for you,  but there is change column arrangement.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/USwTb/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="columnOne">one</div>
        <div class="columnTwo">xzcx</div>
        <div class="columnOne">cas</div>
        <div class="columnTwo">cccccc</div>

        <div class="columnOne">asds</div
        <div class="columnTwo">ccccccccswsww</div>
         <div class="columnOne">wdw</div>
        <div class="columnTwo">ccccccccswsww</div>



    </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    max-width:100%;
}

.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
}

.columnOne {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}

.columnTwo {
    float: left;    
    width: 45%;
}
```